# How to start capture video frame after 20sec from webcam video in python

Tags: python, opencv

Somebody do help me to solve this problem. When the program starts execute, the webcam get starts to capture the video as an input. After 20 sec, want to start capturing the frame and produce it as an output.

Comment: Have you tried using [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) and discarding frames before it? For example, `start=time.time()` before your loop and then just an if like: `if time.time() - start > 20:` and then process do everything

Comment: Hello and welcome at StackOverflow. SO is not a question-answer page as it might seems on first sight. It is always better if we see some type of effort from your side. Show us what you have tried and did not work, we might take it from there.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import cv2
import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

videoout = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mkv", fourcc, cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), (1280, 720))

start = time.time()

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if time.time() - start > 20:
        videoout.write(frame)
```

More information [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).